# Can't access sinatra server from other computers

Tags: ruby, sinatra, shotgun

I am running a sinatra server with shotgun that returns a hello world when request GET in the root (typical tutorial) and works perfectly in my computer. I could only access it from localhost:9393 and then i run it with -o 0.0.0.0 and could access it as IP:9393 but still only from the computer where the server was running.

How can i access the server from other computers? already tried bind 0.0.0.0 and environment production.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more information is needed, like the OS that you are running and if you have made sure that any local firewalls are not blocking your traffic. I see that you marked this with the "Shotgun" tag which tells me that you are running on a *nix system as Shotgun uses forks and windows doesn't support them.

Check your iptables and see if you got anything in there. :)

## iptables -nvL -t nat --line-numbers

## iptables -nvL --line-numbers

Comment: I am running the server in OS X 10.9 and i have no firewalls up. how do i check for iptables?

Comment: Under System Preferences > Privacy & Security > Firewall (tab)

Comment: Checked and the firewall was already off and there was nothing about iptables in the tab, only the option to turn it on and some advanced options that did not seem to be related to the issue.

Comment: All of a sudden i can no longer access the server with ip address even if using -o 0.0.0.0

Comment: `sudo lsof -n -i4TCP:4567| grep LISTEN`

Make sure that you don't have any other version of the application running. Also can you please paste the full command that you are using to start shotgun?

Comment: shotgun basics.rb -o 0.0.0.0, I have also tried this with rerun and ruby. Have only installed it once.

Comment: I ran the line you suggested but only returns a line of data, what am i looking at?
ruby      1558   AJ    9u  IPv4 0xd5fbf659ed0d2b71      0t0  TCP *:tram (LISTEN)

Comment: It means that you have something running on port 4567 which is the default port for sinatra. You need to kill that and then start your app again. I'm sure there's a better way to do this, but try `sudo lsof -n -i4TCP:4567| grep LISTEN | cut -d' ' -f5 | xargs -I {} kill -9 {}` that should kill whatever is running on port 4567. Then start your app again `shotgun -o 0.0.0.0 -p 4567 -s thin myapp.rb`. Hope this helps.